# What is the best way (lossless) to import .skp files into Mathematica?

Tags: import

I am using the free version of Google Sketchup and I've got a few designs in hand, which I need to be able to import into Mathematica. I saw the [similar question asked by @Sjoerd C. de Vries in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246392/importing-google-sketchup-models-in-mathematica), but I didn't find any answer that was simple and allows for complete communication of the information in the skp file to Mathematica. I am asking this question hoping that there has been some progress made in this regard as the previous question was asked in June, 2011.